# How to get Change x and y coordinate of an object if we change the screen resolution in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

If i change the screen resolution then how i will get Change x and y position of an object:

For example my object current x position is 500 and y position is 100 and my current screen resolution is 1360*768

Now i change the screen resolution to 800*600

Then how i will get the changed x and y position of my object.

I am using the following formula to find the changed/updated x and y position:

x = (500 * 800) / 1360;
y = (100 * 600) / 768;

But it is not giving Correct result to me, 
So please Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Firstly, what is the "correct result" you are expecting? If you want to maintain the ratio between coordinates and resolution values, then your formulas **are** correct.

Comment: Either you want new X-Pos to be **294** or new X-Pos to be **60**. Which of those two amounts is more correct for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this formula...

`1360 / 500` gives a ratio of **2.72**. Knowing this ratio you can now use it like so:

`800 / 2.72` = **294** (rounded to a whole number because there is no decimal points in pixel positions). Using the same above logic for height also you should have a final result like...

> Stage Width = **1360** *and* Stage Height = **768** 
>  X-Pos =
>   **500** *and* Y-Pos = **100**

*becomes...*

> Stage Width = **800** *and* Stage Height = **600** 
>  X-Pos =
>   **294** *and* Y-Pos = **78**

To round use `myObject.x = int ( ratio_XPos_result )`